# sed + find value before word in line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, solaris

How can I find the value before the word "free"?

```
top -n1 | grep Mem                   
Mem:  2054968k av, 2034120k used,   20848k free,       0k shrd,  186768k buff
```

First I tried

```
  top -n1 | grep Mem  | awk '{print $7}'
```

but this isn’t good because the free value (here, 20848k) can be in different fields. Sometimes it's field 6, others field 7 and so on.

I need this to work on both Linux and Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v RS="[, ]" '/free/{print a}{a=$0}'
```

**Explanation**

- Set the record separator to `,` and `space`, so the number preceding every string is a record in itself, and so is the string.
- Having everything as its own record, awk will process every item one by one
- For all the records before `free` it will ignore the `{print a}` because the condition doesn't match, and it will skip to `{a=$0}` which will store the currently processed record in variable `a`
- Once `/free/` is matched, awk will just `{print a}` where `a` contains the record right before the match

Comment: Hi this should work on linux and on solaris , is this code support the both OS?

Comment: I only tested it with `GNU Awk 4.1.1`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ top -bn1 | grep free
KiB Mem:   8117084 total,  6578888 used,  1538196 free,   302216 buffers
KiB Swap:  8060924 total,    26004 used,  8034920 free,  1564856 cached
$ top -bn1 | grep -oP '\S+(?=\s+free)'
1544132
8034920
```

requires GNU grep, but you've tagged "linux", so you're OK

For just the "Mem":

```
top -bn1 | grep -oP 'Mem.*\s\K\S+(?=\s+free)'
```

Comment: Hi this should work on linux and on solaris , is this code support the both OS?

Comment: top -bn1 | grep -oP 'Mem.*\s\K\S+(?=\s+free)' ( not work on my linux machine ) I tested it again no any output

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed` (Linux only):

```
top -bn1 | sed -rn '/Mem/{s/.* ([^ ]*) free.*/\1/p;}'
```

Using any `sed`:

```
top -bn1 | sed -n '/Mem/{s/.* \([^ ]*\) free.*/\1/p;}'
```

Using `perl`:

```
top -bn1 | perl -lne '/Mem.* ([\d]+)\s*free/ && print $1'
```

Using a tool designed for the job (tested on Linux, not sure if `free` is available on Solaris):

```
free | awk '/Mem/{print $4}'
```

Another tool designed for the job (should work on both Linux and Solaris):

```
vmstat 2 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Going to the source (this works on Linux, not sure about Solaris):

```
awk '/MemFree/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: about using any sed ( I found problem when - Memory: 7168M phys mem, 2404M free mem, 10G total swap, 10G free swap ) you take the second free , while we need the first one

Comment: @maihabunash I added some other approaches. However, next time, please show us _both_ outputs you need to parse. We don't know what your system will print.

Comment: OK , can you update the top -bn1 | sed -n '/Mem/{s/.* \([^ ]*\) free.*/\1/p;}'    , so it will take the first free value ?

Comment: @maihabunash I could but only if you show me the output you need to parse. Otherwise, I'd just be guessing.